# MVC Preview 5 - ViewData/HTML Helper Quirk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewdata

The following code is in the `/Courses/Detail` action:

```
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public ActionResult Detail(int id)
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = "A View Title";
        return View(tmdc.GetCourseById(id));
    }
```

The `tmdc.GetCourseById(id)` method returns an instance of type `Course` for the View.  In the View I am using

```
<%= HTML.TextBox("Title")%>
```

to display the value of the `Title` property for the `Course` object.  Instead the text box is displaying the string `A View Title`.  Is this normal/expected behavior?  What would be the best way to handle this?

**Update**
As a workaround, I've changed `ViewData["Title"]` to `ViewData["VIEW_TITLE"]` but would like a cleaner way to handle this collision or to know if this is an expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm not at my dev machine right now so I can't test this, but have you tried something like this?

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Title", ViewData.Model.Title) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that behavior is as-designed.  The intention is that you should be able to display (in your view) invalid user input which could never actually be assigned as a property of an instance of your model type.  You can read more about this feature in [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/2008/08/13/asp-net-mvc-tip-32-repopulate-form-fields-with-viewdata-eval.aspx).

Your workaround is fine, but it does highlight the issue of a congested view namespace.  Keep in mind that in addition to properties of your model and ViewData, there is also TempData, ModelState, and HTML stuff in there.

If you always want to display the model property "Title," then you might want to use one of the HTML.TextBox overloads which accepts a literal value instead of a property name.

Comment: Thanks for the help Craig...I forgot about the possible conflicts with TempData and the others.